# Erro fsockopen()

Tags: php

Estou tendo um erro nessa linha, e não sei o motivo, tentei de tudo e não obtive resultado.

Erro:

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to srvstm.com (Connection refused) in kick.php on line 39

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dados_radio");

$ver = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$kikar = $_POST['kikar'];

if($_POST){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs_radio(usuario, ip, data) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['usuario_painel']."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".time()."') ");

    $scfp = fsockopen($ver['ip'], $ver['porta'], &$errno, &$errstr, 10);

    if($scfp){

        fputs($scfp,"GET /admin.cgi?pass=".$ver['senha_kick']."&mode=kicksrc HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: SHOUTcast Song Status (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($scfp)) {

            $page .= fgets($scfp, 1000);

        }

        fclose($scfp);

    }

    echo "<script>alert('Boa sorte. Processo feito com sucesso.')</script>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Já utilizou esta função neste servidor e funcionou? Pois é provável que a diretiva `allow_url_fopen` esteja desabilitada em seu servidor.

Coloque em qualquer lugar de seu código  e visualize as configurações de seu PHP e se a diretiva `allow_url_fopen` está habilitada.

Comment: Estava vendo isso agora que pode estar desabilitada, uso hostgator ai é um problema...

Comment: Será que via .htaccess seria possível?

Comment: allow_url_fopen esta como (on)

Comment: No erro mostra que isso ocorre na linha 39 do arquivo kick.php, onde está este conteúdo? Ficará mais fácil de ver onde está sendo apontado o erro.

Comment: De qualquer forma, tentou excessão `$scfp = @fsockopen($ver['ip'], $ver['porta'], &$errno, &$errstr, 10);` ?

Comment: O Erro é nessa linha ai ela que é a 39

Comment: Quando  eu botei o @ não apareceu o erro mas o sistema não funcionou.

Comment: Certo. @Josimara, não me atentei..... vendo esta linha, estes `&` estão a mais, não estão? Tente assim: `$scfp = @fsockopen($ver['ip'], $ver['porta'], $errno, $errstr, 10);`